# TightVNC grey screen?

Tags: vnc, remote-access, remote-assistance, tightvnc

I'm trying to help my mom remotely with some PC problems.

She's not too computer savvy, so to keep the firewall stuff on my side of things, I tried to use a reverse VNC connection:

- On my machine, I set up TightVNC client in listening mode. I also opened TCP port 5500 on my router and firewall, and checked it using http://canyouseeme.org/.
- On her machine, I (instructed her to) set up TightVNC server, and connect to my machine's IP ('Add New Client...').

Both machines run Windows XP & TightVNC 1.3.10.

**The problem:** 
When she tries to connect, a TightVNC window with grey background pops up on my machine, but I never get to see the remote desktop. It just remains grey.
However, it seems that I control the mouse on the remote side (she says it's moving).

I tried to reverse-connect from another machine on my LAN and it works without a problem.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer, but I like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/de/index.aspx) as a known mom-compatible remote support solution. No firewall troubles here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: (saw your comment just now) That's what I ended up using, works great. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the root need was met by using a different product and there is no further reason to solve the TightVNC problem.